# SWIG: how to wrap *.a library file for Python?

Tags: python, c, swig

I have a big library file, `libcore.a`, generated from a big C language project. My goal is to wrap this library into a package for Python projects. SWIG is the wrapping tool I am going to use. Here is what I did, but failed.

I have made following interface file, coreapi.i:

```
//file: coreapi.i
%module coreapi
%{
#include "coreapi.h"
%}
%include "coreapi.h"
```

and the header file, coreapi.h:

```
//file: coreapi.h
#ifndef coreAPI_H
#define coreAPI_H
extern int coreapi(void* data);
#endif //coreAPI_H
```

and a helper C file, coreapi.c:

```
//file: coreapi.c
extern int core(void* data);   // function defined in libcore.a

int coreapi(void* data)
{
  return core(data);
}
```

and what I tried in command line (note in the last command, `-L./ -lcore` is to link the `libcore.a` file explicitly):

```
$ swig -python coreapi.i   // this generates coreapi.py and coreapi_wrap.c
$ gcc -Wno-unused-result -Wsign-compare -Wunreachable-code -DNDEBUG -g -fwrapv -O3 -Wall -Wstrict-prototypes -I/Users/me/anaconda3/include -arch x86_64 -I/Users/me/anaconda3/include -arch x86_64 -I/Users/me/anaconda3/include/python3.7m -c coreapi_wrap.c
$ gcc -Wno-unused-result -Wsign-compare -Wunreachable-code -DNDEBUG -g -fwrapv -O3 -Wall -Wstrict-prototypes -I/Users/me/anaconda3/include -arch x86_64 -I/Users/me/anaconda3/include -arch x86_64 -I/Users/me/anaconda3/include/python3.7m -c coreapi.c
$ gcc -bundle -undefined dynamic_lookup -L/Users/me/anaconda3/lib -arch x86_64 -L/Users/me/anaconda3/lib -arch x86_64 -L. -lcore -arch x86_64 coreapi.o coreapi_wrap.o -o _coreapi.cpython-37m-darwin.so
```

Everything seems good, but the generated .so file is barely like 57KB while the libcore.a is like 47MB. And when I tried to import it in iPython I got:

```
$ ipython 
Python 3.7.9 (default, Aug 31 2020, 07:22:35) 
Type 'copyright', 'credits' or 'license' for more information
IPython 7.19.0 -- An enhanced Interactive Python. Type '?' for help.

In [1]: import coreapi
---------------------------------------------------------------------------
ImportError                               Traceback (most recent call last)
<ipython-input-1-5427a8938720> in <module>
----> 1 import coreapi

~/coreapi/coreapi.py in <module>
     13     from . import _coreapi
     14 else:
---> 15     import _coreapi
     16 
     17 try:

ImportError: dlopen(/Users/me/coreapi/_coreapi.cpython-37m-darwin.so, 2): Symbol not found: _core
  Referenced from: /Users/me/coreapi/_coreapi.cpython-37m-darwin.so
  Expected in: flat namespace
 in /Users/me/coreapi/_coreapi.cpython-37m-darwin.so
```

Any advice on how to achieve this goal is appreciated. My development environment is Mac OS Big Sur. Thanks.

Comment: I have no experience of building anything for Darwin, but I think you might need the `-all_load` option.

Comment: It looks like you are missing some arguments for the linker. I can recommend using CMake and/or make your core library a shared object.